# Does this still work in order to get master mechanic achievement?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I have read many times that by saving up 1M credits and buying one tier of achievements and then loading, then buying other tier and so on lets you have the master mechanic achievement.

I came across [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/11670/43814):

"As of now, the best way to earn the armory achievements is to play the campaign multiple times, selecting different upgrades on each playthrough, as achievements are shared across all campaigns."

I am confused. I am in the middle of the campaign and I don't want to waste time. So by doing this can I still get the achievement? Or need I play the campaign one other time ?

Comment: If you believe the answer is wrong or outdated, you should question it in a comment or open a bounty on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1

> Buy one series of upgrades.  Get the achievement. Exit campaign
>   without starting a mission.  Re-enter campaign. The upgrades have been
>   re-set, but you still have the achievement.

2

> I just saved up 600k and saved the game under achievements then i just
>   bought everything in one tier then got the achievement then loaded the
>   game up again and did the next tier all with out lossing the money but
>   you keep the achievements.

Quoted from TL.
http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=141420